# JWT authentication stay logged in

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, jwt

I am implementing an authentication system with vuejs on the front and nodejs on the back. When the user logs in a JWT is returned and gets saved on browser's local storage or cookie. Then, I assign a default header with bearer token to all the requests. If I close the tab and open it again, my application looks the local storage and if is a JWT there, it follows the same logic. So until now all good, but what happens if the user closes the application and comes back tomorrow? The same logic will be followed again, but the difference is that my default authentication header will contain an expired JWT and I will get a 401 error. So, the question is, how should I implement an auto login flow because it is bad UX to ask the user for his credentials every time he comes back to my application. Of course I should ask if the last time he visited it was a month ago, but I dont think I should do it every day. One way is to make my JWT expire in one Month but I dont think that is secure enough. Is there any kind of "official" way to implement auto login?

Comment: "One way is to make my JWT expire in one Month but I dont think that is secure enough" well, that's what you're describing.  What is your threshold as to when someone should be logged back in? Your UI should either call something or examine the JWT to see if it's expired and redirect to your login flow.

Comment: The JWT should be valid for let's say an hour, but I want the user to be asked for his credentials if the last time he logged in was let's say amonth ago. So if the user comes back to my app one day after the JWT expired I want a flow of how to refresh a JWT without asking for credentials, maybe using a pair of tokens or something. It should be a protocol about that, and that's what I am asking for.

Comment: 1 Week is my choice and is described in login form as "Stay Logged in for a week". Now the user know for how long the session going to last. I usually forgets my password if don't use for more than couple of weeks. So I guess my users would also feel 1 week is fine.